# VBA error on "Loop Until" statement

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry guys, this is more of an updated question from a previous question... I managed to figure out the issue I was having with regards to clicking the "Next Results" button in IE and looping it back around to pull the same data, then click the "Next Results" button and pull the same data... so on and so on until... and here's where I'm running into the problem. I keep getting an "Object required" error on my "Loop Until" statement... I've tried a number of different workarounds, switching to variables, etc. but still running into errors. Basically I would just like the loop to stop once the "Next Results" button is no longer available (which will obviously happen when there is no more data to pull).

Here's the section of VBA causing the problem...

```
Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
Dim r As Long

Set TDelements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

r = 0

Do
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

For Each TDelement In TDelements

    If TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsContent" Then
        Sheet1.Range("E1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText
        r = r + 1
    ElseIf TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsContent" Then
        Sheet1.Range("E1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText
        r = r + 1
    End If
Next

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each e In elems

If e.Value = "Next Results" Then
    e.Click
    Exit For
End If

Next e

Loop Until e.Value <> "Next Results"

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

IE.Quit
```

Here's the HTML code for the buttons I'm referring to...

```
<table class="contentTable" align="center">
    <tr class="contentTableTR">
<form name="scrollResultListForm" method="post"   action="/scrollTransactionsList.do" onsubmit="return isBusy();">




<input type="submit" name="action" value="Next Results" onmouseover="showComment(event,'Display next results')" onmouseout="hideComment()" class="formButton">


<input type="submit" name="action" value="Last Page" onmouseover="showComment(event,'Goto last result page')" onmouseout="hideComment()" class="formButton">

</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: move the `until` statement from the end of the loop to the `do` statement at the beginning of the loop to create a `Do Until` loop.

Comment: @SilentRevolution at the first `Do` `e` will be `nothing`, how enter the loop? and who is upvoting this? sorry, but that is just wrong :/

Comment: Don't you use `option explicit`  ? `e` is not defined

Comment: add an `On Error Resume Next` that will force the loop start. @DirkReichel, be creative.

Comment: Moving the Until statement to the Do statement at the beginning unfortunately ends with the same result.

Comment: @SilentRevolution if no "Next Results" is found, `e` will be nothing and it will end in an error. `On Error Resume Next` will make the loop never stop anymore... which is not a good idea to do... you are still not checking your suggestions :(

Answer (score 0):

The first question: Is there any `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")` at the "last" page? (I assume this. But I want to be sure)

Try to change your code a bit:

```
....
Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
Dim Next_Loop As Boolean
Next_Loop = True
For Each e In elems

  If e.Value = "Next Results" Then
    e.Click
    Next_Loop = False
    Exit For
  End If

Next e

Loop Until Next_Loop
....
```

If the `For Each` loop end, the variable will be empty and this causes the error. Alternatively you could just change the `Loop Until e.Value <> "Next Results"` line to:

```
Loop Until e Is Nothing
```

But this works only if `e` is declared as an object ;)

**EDIT**

pls try this:

```
Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
Dim r As Long, i As Long
Dim e As Object

Set TDelements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
r = 0

For i = 1 To 1
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

  For Each TDelement In TDelements
    If TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsContent" Then
      Sheet1.Range("E1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText
      r = r + 1
    ElseIf TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsContent" Then
      Sheet1.Range("E1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText
      r = r + 1
    End If
  Next

  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
  Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

  For Each e In elems
    If e.Value = "Next Results" Then
      e.Click
      i = 0
      Exit For
    End If
  Next e

Next i

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
  DoEvents
Loop
IE.Quit
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately adding in the above mentioned code ("Next_Loop") seems to only solve the problem regarding the error, it does click over to the second sheet of data but doesn't pull the data and doesn't continue clicking the "Next Results" button through all the pages. I'm hoping to be able to loop the entire block of code so it pulls the needed data from each sheet until there are no more sheets.

Comment: Thanks again, your edit does help loop it back around but now when it attempts to pull the data I get the error message "permission denied" on the first "If TDelement..." which doesn't make a lot of sense to me because the first version of code I posted would actually pull the data from the second sheet and give me the "Object Required" error on the loop... I'm starting to feel like I'm in an endless loop of errors. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933313/vba-internet-explorer-wait-for-web-page-to-load) can help you a bit... It feels like the page isn't finished loading while some actions where done :/

Answer (score 0):

Your `for each` ends when all `e` are exhausted. Therefore `e` MUST be `Nothing` when you arrive on the `Loop`

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mentioned this in my original post but I'm very much a beginner when it comes to VBA. Could you please elaborate on your answer? How would I apply this suggested fix to my code? Thanks