# VBA: open a website on new tab on IE and wait for it to load

Tags: vba, excel

I recently learned to open websites on IE through VBA excel. Now I'm trying to add code the will check if an active IE is open and if it is, it will open a new tab to navigate the website and do the same thing over again. Unfortunately, the code I have tried doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

```
Sub OpenIE()
Dim IE As Object
Dim site As String

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
site = "https://www.automateexcel.com/excel/"

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate site

Application.StatusBar = site & " " & "is loading"

Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Application.StatusBar = site & " " & "is loaded"

Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You are trying to loop opening the same website twice in different tabs of IE? Opening the second only on successful completion of the first?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933313/vba-internet-explorer-wait-for-web-page-to-load?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @QHarr not acctually loop, more like condition. I want my code that if I run it on the first time it will open a browser and go to the website, and when i run it for the second time it will use the same IE app to open the same website in a new tab... I'm kinda starting to get this using the "Shell.application" but for some reasons my "Do While is looping infinite". I cant debug it

Comment: @QHarr the code that I'm trying to make is like this in the link
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/553580-vba-macro-already-open-ie-window.html #4. But for some reasons the .readystate or .busy is doing an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can open multiple tabs in IE object programatically

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Navigate "https://amazon.com" '1st tab
        .Navigate "https://flipkart.com", CLng(2048) '2nd
        .Navigate "https://snapdeal.com", CLng(2048) '3rd
        .Visible = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
Sub Test()
Dim IE As Object

Set IE = Nothing
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set cell = Cells(1, 1)

For i = 1 To 5
IE.navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS828US828&oq=62654962004&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59.95j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8", CLng(2048)
IE.Visible = True
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. [Reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)