# VBA: Downloading a file behind JavaScript link

Tags: javascript, vba, file, download

How do you write VBA code to download a file sitting behind a JavaScript link? There are many resources on how to download a file from a specific link using VBA, however, none show how to download a file behind a JavaScript link.

In example, how do you download the file behind "Export to Spreadsheet" on this website:
https://www.vanguardinvestments.com.au/retail/ret/investments/product.html#/fundDetail/wholesale/portId=8101/assetCode=equity/?prices

Do we still declare and use urlmon?

```
'Declaration of API function for Office 2010+
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadTOFile Lib "urlmon" Alias         
"URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
    ByVal sZURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
) As LongPtr

#Else
'Declaration of API function for pre Office 2010 versions
Private Declare Function URLDownloadTOFile Lib "urlmon" Alias 
"URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal sZURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
) As Long
#End If

Sub DownloadOneFile()
    Dim FileURL As String
    Dim DestinationFile As String

    'How do you modify this to handle a javascript link?
    FileURL = "https://www.vanguardinvestments.com.au/retail/ret/investments/product.html#/fundDetail/wholesale/portId=8101/assetCode=equity/?prices"
    DestinationFile = "C:\VBA\prices.csv"

    URLDownloadToFile 0, FileURL, DestinationFile, 0, 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fire the event. Credit to [@Greedo](http://%20%20%20%20'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933313/vba-internet-explorer-wait-for-web-page-to-load?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for the principle of waiting for page to load by looping until a specified element is visible in the window. Sorry about the dreaded send keys.

```
Public Sub DownloadFile()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, currPage As HTMLDocument, url As String
    url = "https://www.vanguardinvestments.com.au/retail/ret/investments/product.html#/fundDetail/wholesale/portId=8101/assetCode=equity/?prices"
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.navigate url
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set currPage = objIE.document
    objIE.Visible = True
    Dim myDiv As HTMLDivElement: Set myDiv = currPage.getElementById("price-distribution")
    Dim elemRect As IHTMLRect: Set elemRect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect
    Do Until elemRect.bottom > 0
        currPage.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 10000
        Set elemRect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect
    Loop

    objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("export_icon hideOnSml ng-binding")(0).FireEvent "onclick"

    Application.SendKeys "%{S}"

End Sub
```

If necessary you might add something like the following before the send keys to ensure window is up but seems to work as is at present.

```
    Dim objShell As Shell
    Set objShell = New Shell

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10) 'alter to give enough time for window
    For Each objIE In objShell.Windows
        If TypeName(objIE.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            If InStr(objIE.document.title, "vanguard") > 0 Then
                objIE.Visible = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next objIE
```